# Recording audio and submit to ActiveStorage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, audio, rails-activestorage, web-mediarecorder

I have a Rails form with a file field pointing to ActiveStorage. Using the MediaRecorder API (and a polyfill for Safari), I have also built an audio recorder.

So far so good: the recorded audio can be attached to a `<audio>` element and played, before the form is submitted. As you see below, the code is added as a blob to the `<audio>` tag.

```
<audio controls="" data-target="audio-player.player" preload="true" src="blob:http://localhost:3000/5bb2e66f-afc0-6a46-b3f5-a95564afca55"</audio>
```

The form also allows for a regular file upload of an audio file, which works, and is stored using ActiveStorage, as defined by:

`has_one_attached :audio_file`

Now I want to submit the whole form, including the audio to Rails. The problem is that is is not possible to directly set the `file_field` due to browser security constraints.

So I'm trying a workaround: capture the form `submit`, serialize it and POST with `fetch`. This is also working (the form needed a `remote: true`), the only thing now missing is again the audio.

The working callback is:

```
  var form = self.fileFieldTarget.form;
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(e.target.action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(e.target))
    }).then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  });
```

I see two options:

1) Somehow add the encoded audio to the form json, and have it treated as an ActiveStorage object and then it is all submitted together.
2) Do a separate call to load only the audio, after the rest of form has saved

If some of the HTML / JS looks a bit weird, I am wrapping it all in StimulusJS. I'm happy to share all the audio recording code, if wanted.

[image]

Comment: did you succeed?

Comment: No, ended up rewriting the whole thing in React.